# How can I use the attribute selector with a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use this form because it can handle spaces in my element ID.

```
$("div[id='content Module']").whatever();
```

However I need 'content Module' replaced with a variable?

I tried

```
$("div[id=" + my_var + "']").whatever();
```

but this did not work

Comment: I've never seen the jQuery `.whatever()` method.

Comment: `this did not work` is not an accurate description. What did it do exactly ? At first sight I'd say this should work so are you sure there is an element matching ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a '

```
$("div[id=" + my_var + "']").whatever();
```

Should be

```
$("div[id='" + my_var + "']").whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `$("div[id='" + my_var + "']").whatever();` you forgot the open Apostrof